# Pass data from controller to modal via AJAX (Laravel)

Tags: jquery, laravel, model-view-controller

I call a route which will generate an array from database query then I need to pass it to a modal in a view.

Controller:

```
$logs = DB::table....->get();
return $logs;
```

JS:

```
$('.get-logs').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-logs',
        data: {
            log_date: $t_date
        }
        success: function (data) {
           //show modal with the $logs variable
        },
    });
});
```

View (the button calling the AJAX function):

```
<a class="get-logs" href="#" name="{{ $records[$i]["row_id"] }}">{{ $records[$i]["logs_id"] }}</a>
```

How do I pass the $logs variable to a modal that will show when the anchor tag is clicked?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your ajax call is working fine, ignoring $t_date

```
$logs = DB::table....->get();
return response()->json($logs, 200);
```

And suppose you have date, message in the log

```
success: function (data) {
       for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
         $('.date_column').val(data[i].date);
         $('.message_column').val(data[i].message);
        }
    },
```

Comment: what's the 200 in the response json?

Comment: and also..where's the modal part? will it create a table to display the data?

Comment: And I have assumed, you have two divs with classes date_column and message_column in the modal. You will need to clone the fields for additional data in the modal.

Comment: can you please provide the sample html code in the div? Thanks!

Comment: you can further call $('.modal').modal('show'); in the success method. This is if you are using bootstrap

Comment: Yes, I can show the modal. But can you please share your code where it will create a dynamic table based on the array? Thanks!